# Best way for sending advance email

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, sendmail, html-email

I'd like to send email by asp.net . I use this code and it is work fine.

```
mail.From = new MailAddress("mail@gmail.com", "sender", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
string to = Session["Umail"].ToString();
mail.To.Add(to);
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

mail.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
mail.Subject = "subject";
mail.Body = "body" ;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("Smtp.gmail.Com", 587);
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mail@gmail.com", "pass"); smtp.Send(mail);
```

But I'd like a custom and beautiful mail. Like emails that send from facebook, google team and etc. I know that can use html tag in `mail.Body` but is it good way? What is the best way ?

Comment: Yes, you should use HTML as you describe. I'm not sure what other answer you were expecting?

Comment: I want use so style and image. I think it's not good that use a lot of html and css tag inside of c# code . can I create separate html file and attach it??

Comment: No, you have to include the styles in the email itself. Have a read of this: http://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is ready to use code snippet which I use for sending email which contains both text content and the content based on a html template:

```
        // first we create a plain text version and set it to the AlternateView
        // then we create the HTML version
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        msg.From = new MailAddress("from@email", "From Name");
        msg.Subject = "Subject";
        msg.To.Add("to@email");
        msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        String plainBody = "Body of plain email";

        //first we create the text version
        AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(plainBody, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);

        //now create the HTML version
        MailDefinition message = new MailDefinition();
        message.BodyFileName = "~/MailTemplates/template1.htm";
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.From = "from@email";
        message.Subject = "Subject";

        //Build replacement collection to replace fields in template1.htm file
        ListDictionary replacements = new ListDictionary();
        replacements.Add("<%USERNAME%>", "ToUsername");//example of dynamic content for Username

        //now create mail message using the mail definition object
        //the CreateMailMessage object takes a source control object as the last parameter,
        //if the object you are working with is webcontrol then you can just pass "this",
        //otherwise create a dummy control as below.
        MailMessage msgHtml = message.CreateMailMessage("to@email", replacements, new LiteralControl());

        AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(msgHtml.Body, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html");

//example of a linked image        
        LinkedResource imgRes = new LinkedResource(Server.MapPath("~/MailTemplates/images/imgA.jpg"), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
        imgRes.ContentId = "imgA";
        imgRes.ContentType.Name = "imgA.jpg";
        imgRes.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imgRes);

        msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

        //sending prepared email
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();//It reads the SMPT params from Web.config
        smtp.Send(msg);
```

and these are key parts of the html template:

```
<p>Username: <%USERNAME%></p>

<img src="cid:imgA"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this code that I wanted…
I tested it and it worked fine but when I want to use image in top of the mail, In gmail it’s only attach it and in yahoo mail it’s attach and add image in bottom of mail.
Why my mail did not add this image in correct position??

Comment: I think it is question of your template. I've just tested the snippet against sending to gmail account and the result is that the image is placed in correct position (I've changed its place). In my template the img tag is put into html table i order to positioning it (old way, not by css). I'd mention that LinkedResource embeds the image into email (not by external url).

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like a custom and beautiful mail.
>
> I know that can use html tag in `mail.Body` but is it good way? What is
>   the best way ?

I don't know *exactly* what is that supposed to mean, but generally, there are two ways to do it. (If we talking about images or sources in email etc..)

You can use [`LinkedResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.linkedresource.aspx) class of .NET Framework.

> Represents an embedded external resource in an email attachment, such
>   as an image in an HTML attachment.

*Alternatively*, and more simply in my opinion, if you want to use some images in your email, put the image in a public location then just reference that location in the HTML of the email.